# How to be able to update an input field where redux state resides

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I have a table that list records and has some minimal functionality to update data.  the table is rendered as follows:

```
const renderTableRows = () => {
    return invoices?.map((invoice, i) => (
      <tr
        key={i}
        onClick={() => handleClick(invoice.ID)}
        className={`${InvoiceStatus_Category(invoice.Status)}`}
      >
        <td>
          <span className={`${InvoiceStatus(invoice.DaysFromDueDate)}`}>O</span>
        </td>
        {/* <td className="choice">{invoice.BillToName}</td>
        <td className="choice">{invoice.InvoiceNumber}</td>
        <td className="choice">{invoice.OFFC}</td> */}
        <td>
          <select
            name="status"
            onChange={(e) => handleStatusOnChange(e, invoice.ID)}
            value={invoice.Status}
            placeholder="Change Status"
          >
            <option value={invoiceStatus}></option>
            <option value="Paid">Paid</option>
            <option value="Post&Hold">Post&Hold</option>
            <option value="Instructions">Instructions</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td className="choice">
          <input
            key={i}
            className="matter-input"
            name="matterInput"
            type="text"
            onChange={onChange}
            maxLength={6}
            value={invoice.MatterNo}
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <button
            className="matter-button"
            onClick={() => {
              buttonOnClick(invoice.ID, matter);
              setMatter("");
            }}
          >
            Add Matter
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    ));
  };
```

the state is being populated correctly, but i'm not able to type in the input field.  Is it possible to be able type in this field?  The onChange event as follows:

`const onChange = (e, i) => { const { name, value } = e.target; setMatter(value); };`

I've even tried useRef, but no dice.

Then the button onclick updates the API.  Please see below:

```
const buttonOnClick = (i, mat) => {
if (mat > 0) {
  axios({
    method: "put",
    url: "http://localhost:64198/api/UpdateMatter",
    data: {
      InvoiceID: i,
      Matter: mat,
    },
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  }).then((res) => {
    dispatch(fetchAsyncInvoices());
    setMatter("");
  });
  setMatter("");
  window.location.reload(false);
}
```

};

I would like to type in the highlighted input boxes for new values
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't want to update the redux state each time you type in the input
you have to create a `useState` hook and bind it to your redux state then update this latter only when you need to perform an action:

```js
const [invoicesState, setInvoicesState] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
 setInvoicesState(invoices)
},[invoices])
```

now instead to map through `invoices` you map through `invoicesState`.
the `onChange` function should look something like this:

```js
const onChange = (e, id) => {
  const { value } = e.target;
  setMatter(value);
  setInvoices(prev => prev.map(invoice => {
    if(invoice.ID === id){
      return {
        ...invoice, MatterNo: value
      }
    } else{
      return invoice
    }
  }))
};
```

so you have to pass the id of the invoice to the function to update it

```js
<input
  onChange={() => { onChange(e,invoice.ID) }}
/>
```

**and when you click on the button to update anything you just update your redux state not not the local state**

Comment: @cruz try this updated code

Comment: @cruz for example you have to provide what `invoices` looks like. if it is a state declared like this `const [invoices, setInvoices] = useState([])` then the function I mentioned should work

Comment: I'm sorry. what should i provide to make it more clear? I added the button onclick event as well.  I dont want to update the state in redux.  i'm still learning the toolkit and dont have endpoints to make the updates within redux

Comment: Thanks for your help so far Hatana!  I added the code you provided, but unfortunately I'm still not able to type in the input box.

Comment: did you use `invoicesState?.map` instead of `invoices?.map` ?

Comment: Yes.  I'm able to type in the boxes now, but the MatterNo is not being populated in the input box

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254289/discussion-between-hatana-and-cruz).